# Two different formulas for the calculation of energy in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

There is
$$
E=\frac{h c}{\lambda}
\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
E=\frac{h^2}{2 m \lambda^2}
\,,
\tag{2}
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the object and $\lambda$ is the wavelength.
Can someone please tell me which one is to be used under what conditions?
I am a bit confused.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you find these formulas, respectively? What are $\lambda$ and $m$? What *specifically* is unclear to you about the text that must have accompanied them?

Comment: @ACuriousMind My guess is that they were found in an exam or in an assignment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The De-Broglie approach tells us that the momentum of a wave is
$$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}.$$
Thus for an electromagnetic wave ($m=0$, phase velocity $c$) the Energy is:
$$E=pc=h\frac{c}{\lambda}=h\nu.$$
For a particle with mass $m$, which can also be described as a wave with wavelength $\lambda$ (e.g. electron) the kinetic Energy is calculated with:
$$E_{\rm kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{p^2}{2m}=\frac{h^2}{2m\lambda^2}.$$

Comment: Probably worth adding that both equations can be traced to formulae for energy in terms of momentum. The energy of a photon is $E = pc$ and the kinetic energy of a massive particle is $E = \frac{p^2}{2m}$. Substituting $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$ into both equations gives the desired "quantum" energy equations.

Comment: So here, E=hc/λ is the totel energy of the particle?

Comment: @ParamBudhadev yes because the Photon has no mass and no charge, so it can't have a potential Energy (in a gravitational or electric field).

Answer (score 6):

- The first one $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ should be used for massless ($m=0$) particle.
- The second one  $E=\frac{h²}{2m\lambda²}$ should be used for massive ($m \neq 0$) particles.

Answer (score 5):

The first equation gives the energy of a photon (zero mass) in terms of its wavelength, $\lambda$.

The second gives the kinetic energy of a particle of mass *m* (moving at a speed much less than $c$, the speed of light) in terms of its de Broglie wavelength, $\lambda$.